# How to display a autocomplete selection only when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript code which will give autocomplete prediction.

This code will display the word even if I keep my mouse over that prediction.

Actually I need to display it only when I select a predicition from the list.

See demo here : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uo8wzd06/)

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#tags').each(function(i, el) {
        var that = $(el);
        that.autocomplete({
            select: function( event , ui ) {
                alert( "You searched for: " + ui.item.label );//alerting the selection to the user
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What is the meaning of these line? Can some one explain me ?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#tags').each(function(i, el) {
        var that = $(el);
        that.autocomplete({  
            select: function( event , ui ) {
                alert( "You searched for: " + ui.item.label );//alerting the selection to the user
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be making it harder than it really is.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    focus : function(event) { event.preventDefault(); },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert( "You searched for: " + ui.item.label); //alerting the selection to the user
    }
});
```

should be about enough. Preventing the default event from triggering on the `focus` event will prevent the element over which the mouse is hovering from being displayed in the `#tags` input.